# Проверка строки PHP: только русские буквы и пробел

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Помогите составить регулярные выражения для проверки строки: в ней должны быть только русские буквы и пробелы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если чтобы в пост не пускало, сделайте - проверку перед отправкой. Регулярные выражения + javascript. Перед тем, как передать значения.

Comment: именно регулярное выражение мне и нужно!

Comment: Вот ваша регулярка - /[^а-яА-Я\s]+/msi

Вот так делать проверку 

if(preg_match('/[^а-яА-Я\s]+/msi',$_POST['name'])

echo "не ОК";

else echo "ОК";

Answer (score 3):

```
preg_match('/[^а-яА-Я\s]+/msi',$ваша_строка);
```

Comment: не работает
у меня есть $_POST['name']="Вася Пупкин"
мне нужно что бы в пост не пускало больше ничего кроме русс букв и пробела

Answer (score 0):

```
if (preg_match('/[^а-я ]+/msiu', $value)) {
    echo 'go away';
} else {
    echo 'wellcome';
}
```

Comment: опишите проблему подробнее...ничего ж ведь не понятно...

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Уверен, автор вопроса был бы благодарен за ваш экспертный комментарий к приведенному выше коду.